# Building a surround sound room

Tags: surround-sound, 5.1, plug-ins, home-studio, mixing

If you could build your ideal surround sound mixing room what pieces of gear would you include?  How about sound effects libraries?  Surround plug ins?  Speakers?  Monitor controller?  Anything and everything!

Answer (score 1):

I would start with the THX specs, and then add from there.

http://www.thx.com/professional/sound-engineer/thx-certified-studio-specifications/

Answer (score 0):

I think gear is not so important. There is a lot of gear out there that will do an excellent job. The most important thing is the room itself. I would therefore also start with the THX specs. Sadly the room is probably not only the most important but also the most expensive thing.